# Select last checkbox in IMacros

Tags: checkbox, imacros

I got a few lines of code for an online game.

What does it need to do?

It has to attempt a GTA crime. (works)
Then it has to select the last checkbox and ship the car away to another state.
Now the problem is that it selects the car value like carNum2 or carNum3. But then the next time i steal a car it has to be carNum4 instead of carNum3. So my question is: Is there a way to always select the last checkbox? I found a way to select them all but that didn't work!

Here is the code:

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=CR
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Auto<SP>Burglary
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:selectedCrime[2]
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:autoburg ATTR=ID:carNum2 CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:goState CONTENT=%Pennsylvania-0
TAG POS=7 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=*
```

Thanks anyway!

Plantje!!

Comment: In iMacros you can use xpath for selecting the last tag but unfortunately you didn't include your HTML code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

here is example. it will increment !var1 value and will use to select proper index. Also you can use !LOOP if you ran this code in loop.

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=CR
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Auto<SP>Burglary
Add !var1 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:selectedCrime[{{!var1}}]
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:autoburg ATTR=ID:carNum2 CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:goState CONTENT=%Pennsylvania-0
TAG POS=7 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=*
```

Comment: It's part of a bigger script who runs in a loop.
but its not this line
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:selectedCrime[2]

but its this line:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:autoburg ATTR=ID:carNum2 CONTENT=YES

so does it need to look like this?
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:autoburg ATTR=ID:carNum{{!var1}} CONTENT=YES

Comment: and not every attempt  is succesfull so the increasement by 1 wont work.

Comment: in this case your question is very generic and unclear and I don't think it may add any value to the community.

Comment: oke let me try to explain. u go to autoburglary then u select a crime en press do it when u do it there are 3 options it failed u get caught and end up in jail or u succeed. when u succeed it has to select the last checkbox on ur car list en select a state en press ship. Now everything works accept the part when it does steal a car then i cant get it to work to select the last checkbox. I hope i explained it well enough. Anyway thnx already